# Giving Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template

Tags: smarty

This is my code and it is giving error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error 
      in template "C:\wamp\www\pangu\application\views\front\employer\lesson\topic_popup.tpl" on line 89
"$.post(&quot;{site_url()}(&quot;employer/library/show_topic&quot;);&quot;,{&quot;id&quot;:id,&quot;sts&quot;:sts},function(responseText){" - Unexpected ":", expected one of: "}" , " " , ATTR' 
      in C:\wamp\www\pangu\application\third_party\Smarty-3.1.13\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 665
```

i am new in smarty

```
   <script>
       function show_topic(id,sts){
           if($('#ch_'+id).is(":checked")) {
              sts =1;
           }
           else{
               sts = 0;
           }
           $.post("{site_url()}("employer/library/show_topic");"{"id":id,"sts":sts},function(responseText){});}
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `{literal}` after open `function()` eg:

```
function init_map(){
    {literal}
    scripts
    {/literal}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's problem you have Javasript in your Smarty template.

You should do it in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript"?
{literal}
// here you can put your javascript code safely
{/literal}
</script>
```

However in some cases it's not necessary to use them - look at http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl